# Axios api call doesn't accept parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, store

I am trying to pass the following information to my dispatch function but the values are simply not begin recognized for some reason. They usually come out as undefined

My disptach call in my component:

```
  methods: {
    buscar(){
      const formData = {
        user: this.user,
        password: this.password,
        profile: this.profile
      };
      console.log('fomrdata: ',formData)
      this.$store.dispatch('login', formData)
    }
  },
```

My method in store:

```
login(formData) {
  console.log(formData)
 },
```

All the values exist when i fill in my form and they show up in my component's console.log().

Comment: You have no reference to axios in your question, I presume you're using vuex?

Comment: that is correct. yes. i am using vuex

Comment: is login an action or mutation?

Comment: it is an action

Answer (score 3):

formData should be the second parameter in the action.

```
actions: {
    login ({ commit }, formData) {
        console.log(formData);
    }
}
```

Comment: is {commit} mandatory in every action even if i am not going to to change any state?

Comment: [Actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) should perform an action, for example calling a mutation, which is done via commit. If you're not changing state, why do you need login as an action in vuex? simply put login as a method on the component.

Comment: alright then. thanks. ill test it when i get to work.